# how to restart the timer in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

i am making an application where i am using OTP screen . i worked out with the timer functionality and also able to change the text and show the timer again . my issue is i am not able to restart the timer again. it gets stuck in `00:10`.

Here is my following code please Help !!

```
@IBOutlet weak var butttonName: ButtonDesign!
var countTimer:Timer!
var counter = 10
var restartTimer = false
var isTimerRunning = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
if isTimerRunning == false {
        startTimer()}
}

func startTimer() {
self.countTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1 , target: self, selector: #selector(OTPVerificationViewController.changeTitle), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
isTimerRunning = true
}
@objc func changeTitle()
{
    if counter != 0
    {
        butttonName.setTitle(timeString(time: TimeInterval(counter)), for: .normal)
        counter -= 1
        butttonName.isEnabled = false

    }  else {
        countTimer.invalidate()
        butttonName.setTitle("Resend", for: .normal)
    }
}

@IBAction func verifyButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
if butttonName.currentTitle == "Resend" {
        print("clicked when name is resend !!!")
        if restartTimer == true {
            startTimer()
            restartTimer = false
        }
    } else {
        print("clicked when it is name is verify")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "confirmPassword", sender: self)
    }
}
```

I want to restart the timer whenever the user clicked on "Resend" Button and want to perform segue whenever the user clicked on "Verify" button . both button are the same one i am changing the name on run time

Comment: you can call your `startTimer()` function again

Comment: You are calling StartTime on Varify Button , here you have done 2 mistake - 
1. You had never set restartTimer false.
2. You have to increase counter value 10 again.

Comment: Set restartTimer true in - 
else {
        countTimer.invalidate()
        butttonName.setTitle("Resend", for: .normal)
    }

Comment: And set counter value 10 on startTime() function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restart the counter too

```
if butttonName.currentTitle == "Resend" {
   counter = 10
   // startTimer()
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for quick response it worked ... just one line made me stratch my head from morning

Comment: other than that is can u tell me everything which i have coded is correct ??

Comment: i think you need to remove **restartTimer** variable as it's useless , and it's a good practise to declare the timer optional like **var countTimer:Timer?**

Comment: i am getting an issue . the code is not working for performsegue . i am not able to understand why it creates issue

Comment: it is working . bt it always perform the segue .. whether the buttonName is resend or verify .. still i will try to figure it out . because this thing i have done before also . thank u

Answer (score 0):

Just make the method just like below:

```
 var count = 120
func updateCounter(){
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            if(self.count > 0){
                self.lblTime.text = "\(self.count)"
                self.count = self.count-1
            }else {
                self.lblTime.text =  "0"
                timer.invalidate()
                self.btnresend.isHidden = false // in your case you can change the title of the button
            }
        })
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerMethod), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}

@objc func timerMethod() {
    if(self.count > 0){
        self.lblTime.text = "\(self.count)"
        self.count = self.count-1
    }else {
        self.lblTime.text =  "0:0"
        self.btnresend.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

And from where you want to restart the time just call the update counter method

with set count 120 or you want

```
self.count = 120
```